# pd.read_sql_query single / double quotes formatting

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, pandas, quotes

I'm using Python(Jupyter Notebook) and Postgres Database and am struggling to populate a Pandas dataframe.

The sql code runs fine using the query builder in pgAdmin4 which is

```
SELECT "Date","Close" FROM test WHERE "Symbol" = 'AA'
```

However I can't get this to work in my Jupyter notebook, I assume its something to do with single quotes and double quotes but can't figure out what to change and have hit a wall. In the notebook I'm trying

```
df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT "Date","Close" FROM public.test WHERE "Symbol" = AA', conn)
```

but don't know what quotes to use around the AA (data) part of the query, if I use double quotes pandas thinks AA is a column and if I use single quotes it breaks the string.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Taking a guess: drop the quotes on field names. `df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT Date, Close FROM public.test WHERE Symbol = AA', conn)`

Comment: Have you tried passing your query as a `raw string`?

Comment: This should do it: df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT [Date], [Close] FROM public.test WHERE Symbol = 'AA'", conn). You need to combine single quote with double quotes. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT Date,Close FROM public.test WHERE Symbol = 'AA'", conn)
```

Sql chars must have single quotes, but column names don't need quotes at all.

If you *really* need double quotes inside sql query, then just make sure you use triple outer quotes on python string, like so:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query("""SELECT "Date" FROM public.test WHERE Symbol = 'AA'""", conn)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, taking the column names out of quotes was a big help, also I had to change the column names to all lowercase to get it working. Thanks again, I'd be lost without this site

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, please mark it as accepted, so the future readers will know it. Glad I helped.

Answer (score 2):

You can use triple quotes if you have a huge query, you can declare it over multiple lines like this :

```
df = pd.read_sql_query("""SELECT "Date","Close" 
                          FROM public.test 
                          WHERE Symbol = 'AA'""", conn)
```

Solution from @Marjan Moderc works as well of course.